# Iterate elements and replace new ID and use the ID for attributes in other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append unique ID by iterating multiple `div` with specific class. And use these elements' `id` for specific attribute in other `divs`.

As shown in the snippet, I have iterated `allTabsContent` and replace the original Id with the new one. On the other hand, I want `allTabs` to have an attribute using the new `id` from `allTabsContent`.

---

The code below is causing me to always getting the last `newElementId`.

```js
let productId = '102334';

$('.tab-content > .pdp-tab-content').each(function () {
    let contentId = $(this).attr('fortab');
    let newElementId = contentId + '_' + productId;
    $(this).attr('id', newElementId);
});

$('.nav-tabs > .pdp-tab').each(function () {
    let tab = $(this).attr('tab');
    //let refTab = '#' + tab + newElementId;
    //$(this).attr('href', refTab);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="allergen">Allergen Information</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="overview">Overview</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="nutritionInfo">Nutrition Info</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="prepAndUsage">Preparation & Usage</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content" fortab="allergen" role="tabpanel">                                
      Allergen
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content active" fortab="overview" role="tabpanel">Overview                               
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content" fortab="nutritionInfo" role="tabpanel">
      Nutrition Info
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content" fortab="prepAndUsage" role="tabpanel">Preparation & Usage</div>
</div>
```

---

**Expected Results**

1. New IDs inserted in the children of `tab-content`
2. Use the new IDs for `href` attribute of `.nav-item`

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="allergen" href="#allergen_102334">Allergen Information</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="overview" href="#overview_102334">Overview</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="nutritionInfo" href="#nutritionInfo_102334">Nutrition Info</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link pdp-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" tab="prepAndUsage" href="prepAndUsage_102334">Preparation & Usage</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="allergen_102334" class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content" fortab="allergen" role="tabpanel">                                
          Allergen
      </div>
      <div id="overview_102334" class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content active" fortab="overview" role="tabpanel">Overview                               
      </div>
      <div id="nutritionInfo_102334" class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content" fortab="nutritionInfo" role="tabpanel">
          Nutrition Info
      </div>
      <div id="prepAndUsage_102334" class="tab-pane fade show pdp-tab-content" fortab="prepAndUsage" role="tabpanel">Preparation & Usage</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the end goal for this piece of code?

Comment: @Tekill I want to reuse this piece of HTML for my SPA. So I need to generate unique ID dynamically for each element. This piece of code renders nav tabs using Bootstrap. So during first page load, we are able to switch tabs normally but subsequent rendering we will not be able to switch tabs. This might due to conflicts of IDs.

Comment: your code is working fine,inspect overview and see the id

Comment: problem is with the external link

Comment: @Deepak I'm having issues with adding `href` attribute to the `.nav-item` using the `id` attribute from `tab-content`